# Why my application is not asking for confirmation to exit?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-activity, back-button, back

I have a MasterDetailPage and the detail page is the navigation page. I want PopAsync when detail page stack is > 1. When it's = 1, the application needs ask if the user wants. Currently, 
it's working only when it has 2 pages in stack(root and second one), if you are with 3 pages it pops async all the pages and goes to root page. Also if you are at the root page already, it doesn't asks, simply close the app.

PS: The confirmation dialog is working properly in other parts of app.

```
 public async override void OnBackPressed()
        {
            if (Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.SendBackPressed(base.OnBackPressed))
                await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopPopupAsync();
            else
            {
                if (App.Current.MainPage is MasterDetailPage mdp)
                {
                    if (mdp.Detail.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count > 1)
                        await mdp.Detail.Navigation.PopAsync();
                    else
                    {
                        Alerta alerta = new Alerta();
                        bool opt = await alerta.ShowAlert("confirm", "App name", "Não existem páginas para retornar, você já está na página inicial.", "Continuar", "Encerrar");
                        if (!opt)
                            Finish();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Alerta alerta = new Alerta();
                    bool opt = await alerta.ShowAlert("confirm", "App name", "Não existem páginas para retornar, você já está na página inicial.", "Continuar", "Encerrar");
                    if (!opt)
                        Finish();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What does the exist mean? Close the app? Do you mean it close the app directly and do not ask for confirmation to exit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PCL

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
        {
            base.OnBackButtonPressed();
            // Custom logic for BackButtonPresssed

                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
                    var result = await DisplayAlert("Warning", "Are you sure you want to exit the application?", "Yes", "No");
                    if (result)
                    {
                        MessagingCenter.Send<HomePage>(this, "Shutdown");
                    }
                });
                return true;

        }
```

In Android MainActivity OnCreate()

Add Below Code

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<HomePage>(this, "Shutdown", (sender) =>
                {
                    OnShutdown();
                });
```